# How do I plot facet wrap of varying x width of discrete variable while ensuring the column width is the same throughout

Tags: r, ggplot2

I Am looking for 2 things to achieve a good presentation of my data.

1. Create face wrap of varying with to achieve constant col width throughout.
2. Suitable reorder of stacked cols according to height for easy visual comparison

[image]

Below is my code

```
RI_pH<-data.frame(RI_pH)
RI_pH$Landcover<-factor(RI_pH$Landcover,levels =c("Bare","Vegetation","Mixed"))
RI_pH$Predictor<-factor(RI_pH$Predictor,levels=c("Landsat8","Landsat8 & Sentinel1",
                                              "Sentinel1","All Variables"))

bar<-ggplot(RI_pH,aes(x=Variable,y=RI,fill=Landcover))+
geom_col(width =0.5)+
facet_wrap(~Predictor,scales = "free")+
scale_x_discrete()+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,  hjust=0.95,vjust=0.2, size=32))+
 theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=32))+
theme(strip.text = element text(size=52, face=2))

jpeg(file="bar%03d.jpeg",width=1180,height=849,
  pointsize=52,bg="white",units="mm",res=95)
plot(bar)
dev.off()
```

Comment: You need `scales = "free_x"` to ensure that only the x axis is variable, whereas the y axis has a fixed range. Varying the panel size is going to be easier to do with `facet_grid` using the `space = 'free_x'` option, but this will require two dummy variables to lay the plot out correctly

Comment: What does "suitable reorder" mean specifically?

Answer (score 1):

The only guaranteed automatic way to get constant column widths with varying facet widths would be to have a single row using `facet_grid(scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")`, since there are configurations of data where that would be impossible to accommodate within the built-in constraints of ggplot2 (e.g. facet widths must align from one row to the next).

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(as.factor(gear), wt, fill = as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(~carb, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")
```

[image]

If you want a more customized layout, you might need to lean on packages like `patchwork` to help you combine plots, but I can't think of a straightforward way to keep the column widths aligned between rows.

```
library(patchwork)
a <- ggplot(subset(mtcars, carb <=3), 
       aes(as.factor(gear), wt, fill = as.factor(am))) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(~carb, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") 
b <- ggplot(subset(mtcars, carb > 3),
       aes(as.factor(gear), wt, fill = as.factor(am))) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(~carb, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")
(a / b) + plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

[image]

Comment: Or Thanks Jon, I have adjusted my code to include by changing facet_wrap to facet_grid and added  scales = "free_x", space = "free_x".  Though the width is constant now, it has all the variable are plotted horizontally into 4 columns which am failing to adjust into only 2 cols and 2 rows